# How to solve lsblk error 'symbol lookup error'

Tags: ubuntu, command, undefined, symbols

When I run `lsblk` I get the error

```
lsblk: symbol lookup error: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsmartcols.so.1: undefined symbol: m�mmove, version GLIBC_2.17
```

How can I solve that?

Hardware: Raspberry PI 4B
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (all updates done)

Comment: I get the same error by running the command `fdisk`

Comment: After reboot I got this error : (just one character changed) : `lsblk: symbol lookup error: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsmartcols.so.1: undefined symbol: ,�mmove, version GLIBC_2.17`

Comment: I finally reinstalled ubuntu to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a little late to help the OP, I ran into a similar problem with a symbol lookup error. So I am posting my solution, so it can help others in the future.

The only way I was able to fix a lookup error with `lsblk` was to reinstall `lsblk`. It is not a package you can find in `apt`, but it is inside `util-linux`. So since `util-linux` is already installed, you will have to force the reinstall.

> sudo apt install --reinstall util-linux